# Javascript tabIndex=1 give opposite effect...element gets skipped completely

Tags: javascript, html, tabindex

I can not get this tabIndex to work. I would like it to be the first element(it's a done button but not "button" type) when I hit tab that it goes into. In fact, when I give it a.tabIndex = 1; it does the opposite and gets completely skipped in the normal/default flow of tabbing. Why is this?

```
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "container");
    div.setAttribute("id", "doneCon");
    div.style.width = "70px";
    div.style.height = "35px";
    div.style.overflow = "hidden";
    div.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    div.style.borderColor = "blue";
    div.style.borderRadius = "35px/18px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    div.style.marginLeft = "5px";
    div.style.display = "inline-block";
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    a.setAttribute("class", "a container");
    a.tabIndex = 1
    a.setAttribute("id", "done");
    a.style.display = "block";
    a.style.fontFamily = "yo2";
    a.style.weight = "bold";
    a.style.fontSize = "150%";
    a.style.paddingTop = "7px";
    a.style.textDecoration = "none";
    a.style.color = "blue";
    a.style.textAlign = "center";
    text = document.createTextNode("Done");
    a.appendChild(text);
    div.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: You know the tabIndex line has no semicolon at the end? If that's different to your file, I'd correct the copy here before it's pointed out as the problem.

Comment: [Worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/FV2yY/embedded/result/)

Comment: Reason you set all of those style properties in JavaScript and not just with CSS? It would shrink the code a lot and make it more readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to appendChild `a` to `div` before you set the tabIndex. It is unlikely that the tabIndex will be maintained through this action, because you are appending the anchor (a) to the end of the div's children.

To find out, put a breakpoint on the line after the appendChild and look at the value of the tabIndex property after the append (use firebug, or Chrome's built in developer tool equivalent).